# weblogic 10.3 custom authenticator

Tags: migration, weblogic-10.x, authenticator

we are migrating weblogic from 8.1 to 10.3. We had custom authenticator provider. Is there any standard way to migrate custom authenticator from 8.1 to 10.3? In fact, I could not find the wlManagement.jar in 10.3. I did find a wlManagement.jar file but it only contains .java files, no .class files. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at [Upgrading a Security Provider](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/upgrade/upgrade_sp.html) from the WebLogic 10.3 documentation.

And AFAIK, required classes are in `BEA_HOME\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\wls-api.jar`.